# Display file contents in a web browser from aws s3 bucket

Tags: php, pdf, amazon-s3

Here is what I'm trying to do is display the file contents a file in a browser that is currently located on an S3 bucket.

I'm able to get the file contents from the S3 bucket, by using the following code,

```
    $contents = file_get_contents("/var/general/".$_GET['id']);
```

Next, I'm getting the file information, however, I'm getting a failed to load pdf document error or I'm getting an error message when I'm trying to read a text file.

Here is how I'm trying to read the file:

```
 header('Content-Type: ' . $fileInfo['RevUserFileType']);
 header('Content-Length: ' . $fileInfo['RevUserFileName']);
 readfile($contents);
```

Also, depending on the file type, I'm getting the following message: readfile() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path.

How can I get the file to view within the web page and what will be causing that issue? I'm able to access the S3 bucket, but for some reason, I can't view the contents of the file in the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

It was the following line that was causing the issue.

```
 $contents = file_get_contents("/var/general/".$_GET['id']);
```

So I made the following changes:

```
$contents = "/var/general/".$_GET['id']";
```

and added the following code:

```
 header("ContentEncoding: 'base64'");
```